# How to use apply() with a function that takes more than one input?

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a 10 x 5 data frame and a function that receives 2 inputs `a` and `b`.

`a` is a vector and `b` is an integer.

The function `fun` calculates the mean of the vector `a` and multiplies it by `b` and returns the result. In the following code, I try to `apply()` this function to every column of `x` but it does not seem to work. Help, please!

```
x = data.frame(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))

fun = function(a, b)
{
  c = mean(a) * b
  return(c)
}

apply(x, 2, fun(x,2))
```

Comment: See the help page for `?apply` where it mentions the `...` argument perhaps.

Comment: On a side note, when performing variable assignment, the more common style is R is `<-`.  Most people only use `=` in function definitions or calls, e.g., `fun(a, b=2)`.  Also, the return statement is optional.  If not used, the function will simply return the last value, e.g., `fun <- function(a, b) mean(a) * b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pass more than one parameter to an "apply"-ied function where one of them is the column vector and the other one is a constant,  you can do it in two ways;

```
apply(x, 2, fun, b=2)
```

OR:

```
apply(x, 2, function(x) {fun(x, 2)} )
```

The possibly seen-as-odd behavior of R is that the expression `fun(x,2)` is not a function whereas `function(x) {fun(x, 2)}` is.

```
 apply(x, 2, fun, b=2)
 #------------------
  rnorm.10. rnorm.10..1 rnorm.10..2 rnorm.10..3 rnorm.10..4 
-0.06806881  0.32749640 -0.14400234 -0.41493410 -0.02669955
```

Comment: or even just `apply(x, 2, fun, 2)` though I prefer yours.

Comment: Yes, I prefer naming arguments. Although you see that I didn't do so in the second example because I thought it was closer to how the original failed effort looked.

Comment: Curly braces are not needed here `apply(x, 2, function(x) fun(x, 2))`

Comment: True, curley braces are not needed here, but they will be needed for multi-step procedures and I think it's better to show newbs how to use them.

Comment: @DWin Thank you very much for the answer. It seems to work just that... all the results that I get are `50` which seems unlikely.

Comment: @42- you mention multistep procedures... could you provide a reference to an example? I can't find anything that looks like that. I would like to use the `subset` function within `rapply`...

Comment: You sometimes need to use curley braces to execute operations like `{temp <- fun(x, 2); sqrt(abs(temp))}`. I most often encounter this using `mapply` but I don't think that is the only time when it is needed. I don't really use `rapply` that much.

Answer (score 3):

Here the problem is simple since you have constant value for b. However, if you have two or more than two inputs, you can use these as lists and then use `Map` function. For your example:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata<-data.frame(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
a<-as.list(names(mydata))
b<-as.list(rep(2,5)) # you can keep b<-2 it doesn't change the results since b is constant
myout<-Map(function(x,y) y*mean(mydata[,x]),a,b)
 >myout
[[1]]
[1] 0.2644056

[[2]]
[1] 0.4976899

[[3]]
[1] -0.2673465

[[4]]
[1] 0.2414604

[[5]]
[1] 0.2682734
```